# Tensorflow 2.3, Tensorflow dataset, TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I use tf.data.TextLineDataset to read 4 large files and I use tf.data.Dataset.zip to zip these 4 files and create "dataset". However, I can not pass "dataset" to dataset.map to use tf.compat.v1.string_split and split with \t separator and finally use batch, prefetch and finally feed into my model.

This is my code:

```
d1 = tf.data.TextLineDataset("File1.raw")
d2 = tf.data.TextLineDataset("File2.raw")
d3 = tf.data.TextLineDataset("File3.raw")
d4 = tf.data.TextLineDataset("File4.raw")
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((d1,d2,d3,d4))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda string: tf.compat.v1.string_split([string],sep='\t').values)
```

This is error message:

```
packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 339, in _call_unconverted
return f(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

What should I do?

Comment: Do you really want to use `zip` here? That will iterate through each dataset at the same time. In other words, with each iteration, you have four items (one from each dataset). All four of those items are passed to the map function.

Comment: @jakub Some of my features are in each 200GB file so I think I need to zip them and then shuffle, batch and prefetch some rows. As alternative, I can merge these file and create a very large file and then shuffle, batch and prefetch rows from it. Right? Any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`tf.data.Dataset.zip` function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#zip) iterates over an arbitrary number of dataset objects at the same time. In other words, if you zip over four datasets, you will get four items at each iteration (one from each dataset). This also explains the error OP received

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

The function being mapped needs to be able to handle four arguments, because it is being applied to a zip of four datasets. The code below includes a function that takes four arguments (datasets) and splits them by `\t`. You can map this to the zipped dataset. I substituted the `tf.data.TextLineDataset` objects with sample datasets.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

d1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(["foo\t1"])
d2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(["foo\t2"])
d3 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(["foo\t3"])
d4 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(["foo\t4"])

def split_by_tab(text1, text2, text3, text4):
    sep = "\t"
    return (
        tf.strings.split(text1, sep=sep),
        tf.strings.split(text2, sep=sep),
        tf.strings.split(text3, sep=sep),
        tf.strings.split(text4, sep=sep),
    )

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((d1,d2,d3,d4))
dataset = dataset.map(split_by_tab)
```

---

> As alternative, I can merge these file and create a very large file and then shuffle, batch and prefetch rows from it. Right? Any other solution?

The files could be merged, but if they are large, it's probably not worth doing. I did not realize that the features were split across multiple files. In this case, zipping is a reasonable thing to do.

There is also a library [`tensorflow_text`](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/tensorflow_text/intro) that may be relevant to this question. Might be worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. This is what I was looking for. As I am new with tensorflow, is there anyway I can merge these 4 features sets in split_by_tab function? (In my next step, I basically want to batch, prefetch and feed batch data into model so it would be great if I can merge these 4 features sets inside split_by_tab function.).